# Change Managed Metadata service name for Sharepoint Online

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy

I'm working on migration from SP 2013 to SP Online, name of (Taxonomy) Managed Metadata service is different in Sharepoint online that caused broken link to field type, one solution i was thinking of is to change the name of taxonomy in Sharepoint online but i could not find any option there.

Wanted to know how can i change the name do i need to contact help desk to change it or its some option not I was not able to find.

Answer (score 2):

The Managed Metadata service's name is not possible to change in the SharePoint Online tenant. This service is provisioned automatically by Microsoft when the tenant is provisioned and the customers have no access to rename, delete or create services.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to your migration, I would suggest you implement [hybrid MMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/hybrid/configure-hybrid-sharepoint-taxonomy-and-hybrid-content-types). This will replicate your MMS terms into the SPO term store which then becomes the authoritative source for terms for SPO *and* SharePoint Server (i.e. making any changes to terms, term sets, etc. on-prem will be lost). This does require you to Close the on-prem term sets but allows you to leave them Open in SPO if you need to.